shiny: Take Dependency Only On a Subset of Columns
Assume that I have a reactive which returns a data.frame. I want some of my controls to take a dependency only on a subset of its columns, that is it should only fire, if values in any of the "relevant" columns (here rel_1 and rel_2) change, while changes in the "irrelevant" columns (here irr_1and irr_2) should not trigger a refresh.
I thought creating a reactive which returns only the relevant columns should do the trick, but the following code shows that all the buttons trigger a refresh of the verbatimTextOutput. My expectation would be that a press to Change Irrelevant Columns would not trigger a refresh, because the values in the relevant columns remain unchanged.
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(glue)

dat <- tibble(
  rel_1 = LETTERS[1:3],
  rel_2 = letters[1:3],
  irr_1 = 1:3,
  irr_2 = 101:103
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 4,
      actionButton("chng_all", "Change All Columns")
    ),
    column(
      width = 4,
      actionButton("chng_irr", "Change Irrelevant Columns")
    ),
    column(
      width = 4,
      actionButton("chng_rel", "Change Relevant Columns")
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 12,
      DTOutput("tbl")
    )    
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 12,
      verbatimTextOutput("dbg")
    )    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  my_data <- reactiveVal(dat)
  
  change_values <- function(data, cols) {
    data %>% 
      mutate(
        across(all_of(cols),
               ~ if (is.numeric(.x)) sample(100, 3) else sample(LETTERS, 3))
      )
  }
  
  relevant_data <- reactive(
    my_data() %>% 
      select(starts_with("rel"))
  )
  
  observe({
    my_data(change_values(my_data(), c(paste0("irr_", 1:2),
                                       paste0("rel_", 1:2))))
  }) %>% 
    bindEvent(input$chng_all)
  
  observe({
    my_data(change_values(my_data(), paste0("irr_", 1:2)))
  }) %>% 
    bindEvent(input$chng_irr)
  
  observe({
    my_data(change_values(my_data(), paste0("rel_", 1:2)))
  }) %>% 
    bindEvent(input$chng_rel)
  
  output$tbl <- renderDT(
    datatable(my_data())
  )
  
  output$dbg <- renderPrint({
    glue("Relevant Data Last Changed: {Sys.time()}")
  }) %>% 
    bindEvent(relevant_data())
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


We can achieve the desired behavior by using a reactiveVal instead of reactive:
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(glue)

dat <- tibble(
  rel_1 = LETTERS[1:3],
  rel_2 = letters[1:3],
  irr_1 = 1:3,
  irr_2 = 101:103
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 4,
      actionButton("chng_all", "Change All Columns")
    ),
    column(
      width = 4,
      actionButton("chng_irr", "Change Irrelevant Columns")
    ),
    column(
      width = 4,
      actionButton("chng_rel", "Change Relevant Columns")
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 12,
      DTOutput("tbl")
    )    
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 12,
      verbatimTextOutput("dbg")
    )    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  my_data <- reactiveVal(dat)
  
  change_values <- function(data, cols) {
    data %>% 
      mutate(
        across(all_of(cols),
               ~ if (is.numeric(.x)) sample(100, 3) else sample(LETTERS, 3))
      )
  }
  
  relevant_data <- reactiveVal()
  
  observe({relevant_data(
    my_data() %>% 
      select(starts_with("rel"))
  )})
  
  observe({
    my_data(change_values(my_data(), c(paste0("irr_", 1:2),
                                       paste0("rel_", 1:2))))
  }) %>% 
    bindEvent(input$chng_all)
  
  observe({
    my_data(change_values(my_data(), paste0("irr_", 1:2)))
  }) %>% 
    bindEvent(input$chng_irr)
  
  observe({
    my_data(change_values(my_data(), paste0("rel_", 1:2)))
  }) %>% 
    bindEvent(input$chng_rel)
  
  output$tbl <- renderDT(
    datatable(my_data())
  )
  
  output$dbg <- renderPrint({
    glue("Relevant Data Last Changed: {Sys.time()}")
  }) %>% 
    bindEvent(relevant_data())
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

Winston Chang explained this here as follows:

In short: Invalidation starts with reactive values, and it "pushes"
invalidation downstream immediately to all descendants. But executing
reactives starts from the other end. During the flush cycle, observers
"pull" their input values, executing upstream reactives only when
necessary.

Please also see this related blog post.

Ahh, beautiful and yet so easy to implement in my project without tons of changes. You really made my day!!!
